# Android: Menu on bottom of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I am developing an Android application for the SPen . I am having some trouble getting the bottom menu within a *LinearLayout* to show up below the *SCanvasView* within a *ReletiveLayout*.  It must be an attribute I set within canvas_container since I can show the bottom menu when I set the height of the canvas_container to a specific size.

The attribute I am giving the bottom menu is android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

**To simplify the layout: I just want a menu bar on top and the bottom (both containing ImageViews) and the space in between them to be filled with a *SCanvasView* and an *ImageView* (both the same size).**

Here is some simplified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">                               
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/iv_top1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/topimage1"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/iv_top2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/topimage2"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>           
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/menu4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">  
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/iv_bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottomimage1"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>
        <ImageView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/iv_bottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottomimage1"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView 
            android:id="@+id/canvas_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misunderstood but a `LinearLayout` with vertical `orientation` would probably be better in this situation. This way you can use `weightSum`. Set the `weightSum` to 4 then the weight of each `LinearLayout` for the menus to 1 and the `RelativeLayout` weight to 2 or adjust that according to what you want.

Also note that `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property. And when using `weights` and `weightSum` you want your `width` for each `View` to be `0 dp` for `horizontal orientation` and `height` set to `0dp` for `vertical orientation`

Comment: weight at bottom may differ for different screen sizes